# How to get access to private repository of the same project inside an Azure pipeline on Ubuntu?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The use case is that we have a node.js project which has one dependency pointing to another private repository within the same project like this:

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-package": "git+https://myorganization.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/myproject/_git/myotherrepo#mybranch"
  }
}
```

No the step which runs `npm install` fails because of failing authentication.

It seems like the ubuntu VM on which the pipeline is running has no access rights to any of the repositories.

Comment: Where do you host this private repo?

Comment: Like I said in the same Azure project.

Comment: What about multi repo https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the credentials for the private repo even they are in the same project. See below example:

You can explicitly enter the [Personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) in your private repo url. This way is not recommended, for it will expose your PAT in the package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-package": "git+https://PersonalAccessToken@myorganization.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/myproject/_git/myotherrepo#mybranch"
  }
```

The more security way is to add the PersonalAccessToken during the pipeline execution. See below example:

1, Define your package.json like below, Using a token (ie.`#{Token}#`)replace the PAT.

```
"my-package": "git+https://#{Token}#@myorganization.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/myproject/_git/myotherrepo#mybranch"
```

2, Add a task before npm install task to replace the `Token` with the predefined [system.accesstoken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken). For example task: [RegEx Match & Replace](https://github.com/kasunkv/regex-match-replace-vsts-task). Configure the task like below.

```
- task: kasunkodagoda.regex-match-replace.regex-match-replace.RegExMatchReplace@2
  displayName: 'RegEx Match & Replace'
  inputs:
    PathToFile: package.json
    RegEx: '#{.*}#'   ##match #{Token}# in the package.json 
    ValueToReplace: '$(System.accesstoken)'
```

3, If you are using classic pipeline. You need to enable `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` in order to get value of the predefined system.accessstoken in step 2. See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I found out that azure has a build in task for token replacement which does basically the same like your task.